# Why do I only get NaN och Inf at ODE45 simulation in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, nan, openmodelica, ode45

I'm using Octave with ODE45 to simulate a system of ODE equations. But the problem is that the ODE simulation gives wrong values. Have a look at this Octave code:

```
function dx = dynamik(t, x)
b1 = 1000;
b2 = 2000;
m1 = 10;
m2 = 7;
M = 2000;
g = 9.82;
mu = 0.3;
L = 0.1;
Ap = 0.004;
Am = 0.002;
Pp = 2*10^6;
Pm = 2.1*10^6;
k1 = 1.78e+4;
k2 = 4.04e+4;
k3 = 8.86e+3;

dx= [ x(2);
    -k1/m1*x(1) + k1/m1*x(3) - b1/m1*x(4) + b1/m1*x(4) + Ap/m1*Pp - Pm*Am/m1*x(2);
    x(4);
    k1/M*x(1) - k1/M*x(3) + b1/M*x(2) - b1/M*x(4) - g*mu*x(4) - k2/M*x(3) + k3*L/M*sin(x(5));
    x(6);
    3*k2/(m2*L)*x(3) - 3*k2/m2*sin(x(5)) - 3*k3/(m2*L^2)*x(5) - 3*b2/(m2*L^2)*x(6) + 3*g/(2*L)*sin(x(5))];
endfunction

tspan = 0:0.5:10;
init = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
[t, y] = ode45(@dynamik, tspan, init);
```

This gives:

```
>> y
y =

0.0000e+00    0.0000e+00    0.0000e+00    0.0000e+00    0.0000e+00    0.0000e+00
1.6659e+08   -6.9253e+10   -1.9336e+05    8.0380e+07   -4.4787e+07    3.8388e+12
5.9331e+18   -2.4665e+21   -6.8864e+15    2.8628e+18   -1.3333e+32    1.1428e+37
2.1131e+29   -8.7843e+31   -2.4526e+26    1.0196e+29   -3.9691e+56    3.4019e+61
7.5258e+39   -3.1286e+42   -8.7350e+36    3.6313e+39   -1.1816e+81    1.0127e+86
2.6803e+50   -1.1142e+53   -3.1110e+47    1.2933e+50  -3.5174e+105   3.0148e+110
9.5460e+60   -3.9684e+63   -1.1080e+58    4.6060e+60  -1.0471e+130   8.9747e+134
3.3998e+71   -1.4134e+74   -3.9461e+68    1.6404e+71  -3.1171e+154   2.6717e+159
1.2109e+82   -5.0337e+84   -1.4054e+79    5.8425e+81  -9.2794e+178   7.9533e+183
4.3125e+92   -1.7928e+95   -5.0054e+89    2.0808e+92  -2.7624e+203   2.3676e+208
1.5359e+103  -6.3849e+105  -1.7827e+100   7.4109e+102  -8.2234e+227   7.0482e+232
5.4701e+113  -2.2740e+116  -6.3491e+110   2.6394e+113  -2.4480e+252   2.0982e+257
1.9482e+124  -8.0989e+126  -2.2612e+121   9.4003e+123  -7.2875e+276   6.2461e+281
6.9386e+134  -2.8844e+137  -8.0534e+131   3.3479e+134  -2.1694e+301   1.8594e+306
       NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
       NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
       NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
       NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
       NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
       NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
       NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
```

But in OpenModelica, I have this code:

```
model Hydraulik_System_1
// Types for variables
type PositionCylinder = Real(unit="m");
type Position = Real(unit="m");
type Velocity = Real(unit="m/s");
type DegreesPosition = Real(unit="rad");
type DegreesVelocity = Real(unit="rad/s");
type pressure = Real(unit="Pa");
type flows = Real(unit="l/min", min=0.0);

// Types for parameters
type spring = Real(unit="N/m");
type damper = Real(unit="Ns/m");
type mass = Real(unit="kg");
type friction = Real(unit="%");
type length = Real(unit="m");
type gravitation = Real(unit="m/s^2");
type area = Real(unit="cm^2");

// Parameters
parameter spring k1 = 1.78*10^4;
parameter spring k2 = 4.04*10^4; 
parameter spring k3 = 8.86*10^3;
parameter mass m1 = 10;
parameter mass m2 = 7;
parameter mass M = 2000;
parameter damper b1 = 1000;
parameter damper b2 = 2000; 
parameter gravitation g = 9.82;
parameter friction mu = 0.3;
parameter area Am = 0.002;
parameter area Ap = 0.004;
parameter length L = 0.1;
parameter pressure Pp = 2*10^6;
parameter pressure Pm = 2.1*10^6;

// Variables
PositionCylinder x1;
Position x3;
Velocity x2 , x4;
DegreesPosition x5;
DegreesVelocity x6;
initial equation
x1 = 0;
x2 = 0;
x3 = 0;
x4 = 0;
x5 = 0;
x6 = 0;
equation

der(x1) = x2;
der(x2) = - k1/m1*x1 + k1/m1*x3 - b1/m1*x4 + b1/m1*x4 + Ap/m1*Pp - Pm*Am/m1*x2;
der(x3) = x4;
der(x4) = k1/M*x1 - k1/M*x3 + b1/M*x2 - b1/M*x4 - g*mu*x4 - k2/M*x3 + k3*L/M*sin(x5);
der(x5) = x6;
der(x6) = 3*k2/(m2*L)*x3 - 3*k2/m2*sin(x5) - 3*k3/(m2*L^2)*x5 - 3*b2/(m2*L^2)*x6 + 3*g/(2*L)*sin(x5);

end Hydraulik_System_1;
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

Can you tell me why this happens to my simulations? There's a huge difference between the OpenModelica simulation result and the Octave simulation result. Why? It does not matter if I change the ODE solver. The results will be almost the same.

Comment: Looking at that data, because the numbers are too big. The likely reason: there is some typo in your equations

Comment: No! I found it. I use ode23s. Now it works!

Comment: OK -- I was able to reproduce your errors when I installed odepkg.  The `ode23` function also goes to NaN, but it takes a little longer to get there.  However, `ode23s` works.  (As does `lsode`.)  The conclusion is that your equations are "stiff," so Standard Runge-Kutta methods such as ode23 and ode45 are not appropriate.

Comment: How do I determine if equations are stiff or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used lsode, and got the right answers, too, but the call parameters had to be switched, and a smaller tspan.

First, swapped the parameters in the function:

```
function dx = dynamik(x, t)
```

Set tspan:

```
tspan = 0:0.0625:2;
```

Then the `lsode` call:

```
[y,t] = lsode(@dynamik, init, tspan );
```

Update: Installed `odepkg`, and was able to reproduce your error.  Also saw the error with `ode23`, but not with `ode23s`.  This indicates that your ODE is "stiff," so Runge-Kutta 4/5 is not really an appropriate algorithm.

Comment: It gives error for me if I use lsode: error: dynamik: A(I): index out of bounds; value 2 out of bound 1

Comment: That's because your parameters are in the wrong order.  That's why I switched them in my answer.